# Generate a unique ID (As much As possible) from a string in Excel using string functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have two strings in two cells

Cell A1 = Customer Country
Cell B1 = Customer City

I need to generate a unique ID using the Excel string functions (LEN, LEFT, MID, RIGHT etc.) or any other (CONCAT etc.) along with the ROW function.

Get first letter & last letter of each word, remove spaces and dashes, get the row number and return a unique string.

If I use

```
=IF(LEN(A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1," ",""))=0,LEFT(A$1,1),IF(LEN(A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1," ",""))=1,LEFT(A$1,1)&MID(A$1,FIND(" ",A$1)+1,1),LEFT(A$1,1)&MID(A$1,FIND(" ",A$1)+1,1)&MID(A$1,FIND(" ",A$1,FIND(" ",A$1)+1)+1,1))) &ROW(A$1)
```

I get results as CC1 in both cases. How would I get a unique ID in such as case.

Comment: Add the column index of the cell as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea in the comment-section by @JosWoolley is a good one. Though, be careful how/where you'd add a column index. If you'd just add the column index number you'd create confusion between say `CC111` from row `11` column `1` and the number from row `1` and possibly column `11`. Just adding the actual address of the cell instead of these indices will help but can create confusion too if you don't add a delimiter first. Therefor I'd suggest something along the lines of:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")),"|",ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4))
```

---

**Note:** If you don't yet have access to `TEXTSPLIT()` you can swap this with `FILTERXML()`. Also, you mentioned `CONCAT()` but if used with Excel 2019 you may need to CSE the formula.